# Orion chronological consultation

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus, fiware-sth-comet

I would like to know if it is possible to consult older data using orion Context Broker.

EG: I have a temperature attribute and the value is constantly changing (4,5,9,10,30,2). In the examples and specification i had the impression it is only possible to consult the latest value (in this case 2).

Is this accurate? if so is the older data deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's correct. That's the way in which Orion works, and makes sense for the most of the use cases. Orion is a context broker, so whenever the context changes (and an attribute value is part of that context) then Orion returns the new value.

However, if you want to have *historical context* there are FIWARE solutions for that. In particular, [Cygnus](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus) can be used to persist such historical context in several storage backends (HDFS, MySQL, CKAN, etc.). Among these backends, the [Short Term Historic](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-sth-comet) could be particularly interesting in your case, given that its provides a NGSI-like REST API interface for getting secuences of values, as the one you are showing.

Please have a look to the documentation on these componentes for further details.

Comment: I took a look at the documentation and installed Fiware STH. The problem is that when i subscribe to an orion context then consult, the values are null. In the STH log it says: ERROR when collecting the raw data collection for retrieval (the collection may not exist). I will create another post for this specific issue. Thank you very much.

The post can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45867677/sth-getting-historical-raw-context

Comment: Great! That's the way... using new question post for new problems. I hope STH experts could have a look and answer.