# STH getting historical raw context

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-sth-comet

I installed Orion and Fiware STH in order to use the minimalistic option.

The problem is that when i subscribe to an orion context then consult, the array is null.

```
"name": "temperature",
"values": []
```

In the STH log it says:

> ERROR when collecting the raw data collection for retrieval (the collection may not exist).

I noticed that when i try to unsubscribe it returns a `200 OK` message with the following body:

```
{
    "subscriptionId": "xxx",
    "statusCode": {
        "code": "404",
        "reasonPhrase": "No context element found",
        "details": "subscriptionId: /xxx/"
    }
}
```

EDIT: The request URL is:
    192.168.60.117:8080/STH/v1/contextEntities/type/room/id/Room‌​1/

```
(In my case the type is "room" and not "Room"). The headers are Accept, 
Content-Type, Fiware-Service, Fiware-ServicePath
```

Comment: Is there actually the entity registered already in Orion? How is your HTTP request code? How did you create your entity in Orion Context Broker? Are you able to get the temperature value from your entity doing an HTTP GET to Orion directly?

Comment: Yes, there is an entity registered in Orion. I tried using v1 and v2.

I am able to get the temperature value directly from orion.

I didn't understand this question: How is your HTTP request code?

Comment: Please put also the code you are using for your request (the same that is resulting an empty array).

Comment: http://192.168.60.117:8080/STH/v1/contextEntities/type/room/id/Room1/attributes/temperature?hLimit=10&hOffset=0&dateFrom=2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z&dateTo=2017-11-30T23:59:59.999Z

(In my case the type is "room" and not "Room"). 

The headers are Accept, Content-Type, Fiware-Service, Fiware-ServicePath

Comment: Update your question with this information...

Comment: Any idea on what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like more a  problem when you make the subscription to ORION than when the data is processed by STH,  you can find how to make the subscription in Orion and  how to notify to STH in this link: https://fiware-sth-comet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data-storage/index.html, Also, if you provide more information of how you make the subscription and the logs I could have a better view of where is the problem and I can help you in a better way.